# A regular expression to remove quotes when there is no whitespace in between

Tags: php, regex

I want to remove quotes in a string when there are no whitespaces between those quotes.
Here is an example:
    "foobar" should be foobar
    "foo bar" should be "foo bar"
I am using php and preg_replace()

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just match non-whitespace and quotes: `"([^[:space:]"]\+)"`...

Comment: @Merlyn It seems that you're the only one to get the point of this question...

Comment: @dader: Too bad I don't know PHP.  If you do, feel free to swipe my comment and add an answer ;)

Comment: you're answer is fine but i would have done it that way ( a correction of Amber's answer ) : preg_replace('!"([^\s"]++)"!', '$1', $string );
assuming only dbl quotes are used :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/"([a-z0-9]+)"/iU','$1',$string);
```

Comment: Note that this will only work if you only want to remove quotes around letters, and nothing else.

Comment: This keeps the quotes if there are non-letter characters, not when there are non-whitespace characters. Think `"abc1de"`.

Comment: it's pretty simple to add the stuff you need inside []

Comment: I modified it so it looks like this: '/"([a-zA-Z0-9]+)"/iU','$1'

Comment: thanks think to give +1 or accept if this satisfied you. Also you don't need uppercase there because i have added i modifer

Comment: One more question, can it be modified so that it doesn't remove any quotes inside a html style tag?

Answer (score 1):

```
$outputstr = preg_replace('/"(\S+)"/', '$1', $inputstr);
```

Comment: I think this might have greedy problems if there are multiple quoted strings on a line.

Comment: this answer was completly wrong intially because you didn't even put $1 in the replace part neither any parenthesis around \S.

Comment: @Merlyn: only if those strings are not separated by whitespace. @yes123 - as it turns out, the edit functionality is there for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

none of the answers posted, including the accepted one, takes pairing into account, therefore  strings like `"foo bar"baz"spam ham"` will be handled incorrectly. You need actually need something like:

```
$str = ' "foo bar"baz"spam ham" ';
echo preg_replace_callback('~"(.+?)"~', function($m) { 
    return preg_match('~\s~', $m[0]) ? $m[0] : $m[1];
}, $str);
```

To OP: please do not accept wrong answers. This confuses googlers and lowers the value of SO as a knowledge base.

Comment: never heard of `U` modifier like in my answer i guess. Think twice before saying the wrong

Comment: Also your regex matches string with space beteween because of the `.`.

Answer (score 0):

or play with negative lookaheads

php> echo preg_replace('/"(?!.*?\s+.*?)/', '', 'what "foo bar" "foobar"');

what "foo bar" foobar

of course that one needs some work, won't work with nested quotes and the like. but you get the picture.